# How to access a specific index of a List<CustomClass>();

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have a custom class called Tile. I have a list of tile objects:

```
List<Tile> openList = new List<Tile>();
```

Later on in my code I try to access the first object in the list. I know it is not empty because my `Debug.Log` clearly shows that I have Tiles in `openList`.

```
foreach(Tile t in openList)
  Debug.Log ("Gscore of Tiles in openlist: " + t.getGScore());
Tile current = openList [0];
```

However when I run this I get an error when it comes to `Tile current = openList[0];`

The error is:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Tile].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
>   AStar.nextLayer () (at Assets/Scripts/AStar.cs:90)

For the life of me I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm sure it is something stupid that I am overlooking. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong or how to access the List by index I would really appreciate it.

thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? If the list is not empty, it should work... Is the list also used by another thread?

Comment: @samar Because she wants the first item in the list, not every item in the list.

Comment: What happens if you pause the debugger on the `openList[0]` line and check the value of `openList.Count` in the Watch window?

Comment: The `foreach` loop workfs fine if the list is empty. Are you sure you see the logged message?

Comment: by any chance t.getGScore() doesn't manipulate the list in some way that you don't want to? (removing items, setting it to null...)

Comment: @AlexandreMachado If the list was modified within the `foreach` loop, an exception would be thrown.

Comment: @helb You are right about the re-enumeration, but setting it to null will still pass

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on why the list suddenly seems to be empty, but a safer / cleaner way to get the first item in a collection is this :

```
Tile current = openList.FirstOrDefault();

/* OR : as suggested by David Pfeffer, a faster, less wasteful check */
Tile current = openList.Count == 0 ? null : openList[0]

if(current != null)
{
  //do something with current
}
```

Comment: I disagree with this, because `FirstOrDefault` will have to treat the list like an enumerable, creating an enumerator object and moving forward in the list by one. Part of the appeal of an array or list is direct indexing.

Comment: Then why use a `List<T>` at all?

Comment: using `.Any()` will do the exact same thing, but won't return the object.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: If there isn't any advantage to be had in using .net's `List<T>` over using plain old arrays, why would anyone use it at all?

Comment: Lists can change in size, and arrays cannot. I didn't imply there wasn't an use for list; I said that `FirstOrDefault` on a list is wasteful.

Comment: Oh i agree that it's wasteful, and if you have a more efficient way i'd love to hear it.
I answered this because i can't think of any less wasteful ways to do it without telling OP to refactor all his/her code ;)

Comment: `openList.Count == 0 ? null : openList[0]`

Comment: @DavidPfeffer It's not true. `FirstOrDefault` implementation checks if the underlying type is `IList<T>` and will verify `.Count` property first if it is. Using `FirstOrDefault` is more readable then your version with ternary operator.

Comment: Woah. 
I had a feeling that's what it would do (simply because that would make sense).
The odd thing is, when i ran timed unit tests to do this, the `FirstOrDefault` was consistently the slower one of the two.
So perhaps, it *is* more wasteful, but for another reason.

Comment: Added to that, `FirstOrDefault` is sometimes dangerous because the default value depends on the type of object. (if i had a list of ints, i would get back `0` instead of `null`)

Answer (score 0):

What is the code that populates the list. The error is Argument out of range so either the list is not being populated or is empty. You should look into why the index is out of range.

Comment: Yes it answers that his index is out of range and that he should look into why the index is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same error when I did this:

```
List<int> openList = new List<int>(0);
```

But when I did the following it worked.

```
List<int> openList = new List<int>();
openList.Add (0);
```

So I'm guessing that even though the item in the list exists, it hasn't been correctly constructed, so it's an item in List that is pointing to nothing. And this is interpreted as an out of range.
I'm presuming a lot of this, but it works.